# Change background color of boostrap dropdownlist when it becomes active using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the background color of dropdownlist when i clicked on it. hover works fine but active/focus did not work.I used this in my navigation bar.

```css
.btn-danger {
  background-color: #800080;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #800080;
}

.btn-danger:hover {
  background-color: #17a2b8;
}

.btn-danger:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.btn-danger:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Portfolio<span class="caret"></span>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="https://www.jquery-az.com/">PS</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.jquery-az.com/">HS</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.jquery-az.com/">BV</a></li>
        </ul>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to change the `dropdown-list` after you've clicked on the `dropdown-toggle`, not on the list itself. In this case, the following should do the trick:

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Make sure you give your elements an `id` or a differentiating class because otherwise all your dropdown menus will be in that color.

Comment: I added the below code in my css,it works fine..btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle{background-color: #17a2b8;}